# In Excel how to add or subtract 2 different columns to the third column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have 3 columns (A,B,C).

Column A cells I want to add to column C cells.
Column B cells I want to subtract from column C cells.

I want column C to be a running total that has added (Column A, deposits) or subtracted (Column B, withdraws) per line.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have titles in row 1 and begin with a zero in C2, you could paste in C3:

```
=C2+A3-B3
```

Then copy the cell C3 to the following rows of the column C (as much as you need it).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're trying to make a Statement of Account form. There are templates available for this. [This is the template I prefer.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/statement-of-account-TC006078400.aspx)

This uses an =IF statement to display the value if there are numbers placed in the fields. Check it out.

- C= Charges (Debits)
- D= Credits (Payments)
- E= Account Balance

  =IF(ISERROR(IF(OR(C12,D12),((E11)+C12-D12),)),"",IF(OR(C12,D12),((E11)+C12-D12),))

You can see from this code, ((E11)+C12-D12), it draws from the previous line for a source.